MySQL JSON column storage size issue
We are using the JSON column in the table. For a particular row when we checked the JSON_STORAGE_SIZE( table.json_column) the size used is 280KB. But the plain text JSON data size is just 1kb and also when we checked the size required to store that data in json column SELECT JSON_STORAGE_SIZE('JSON_data'), the size required was 1.5kb.
Can someone explain why the table consumes more storage size? What can we do to fix this?

There may be several causes. What it seems more plausible is that particular column of that particular row to have been updated at some point in the past, causing the data stored there to be smaller now than it was. Space management of MySQL rows is complex, and more for JSON-based column.
You could check the value returned by JSON_STORAGE_FREE(table.json_column) for that row and column to see if the difference in storage is now free space reserved.
